# Python mlrose issue - error: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm working on a Travelling Sales problem using the mlrose.TravellingSales python function - trying to pass a parameter 'distances' through, which calls for a list of triples.

I'm getting 'IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed' when it tries to use my list.

```
dist_list = list(distances_df_dealers[['origin', 'destination', 'duration(minutes)']].sort_values(by=['origin', 'destination']).to_records(index=False))
dist_list[:5]
```

Output: [(0, 1, 24.66666667),
(0, 2, 31.2),
(0, 3, 44.25),
(0, 4, 34.68333333),
(0, 5, 33.)]

```
fitness_dists = mlrose.TravellingSales(distances = dist_list)
```

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed